# Node js refresh token using cookies and redis but multiple devices

Tags: node.js, express, redis, jwt

I’m developing a system of authentication with an access token and refresh token, saving this one on redis by using the key:userId and value:refreshToken.
Now, I realized that with this system the user is not able to access with other devices. So, I was thinking to save the refresh token for each device.

Is there a good way saving the session id ( with express-session) and ALSO a cookie with the refresh token? What is the best way for doing this using redis? Should I don’t use redis at this point and just working on database? In this case i will use a simple table with id user and refresh token as columns.

Comment: appending the `accessToken` to the key (`${userId}-${accessToken}`) solves the problem?

Comment: thank you very much @LeibaleEidelman, indeed! At last I'm using this patter but with the semi-colon of separator instead.